# Way to change slack status automatically at regular intervals?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I'd like my slack status to change automatically and randomly every half hour, but I don't know how to make something that would do that for me. Can someone recommend a tool for smallscale personal web automation?

Comment: [This](https://api.slack.com/docs/presence-and-status) and a cron job should do this.